laravel middleware cannot read Auth
I have this middleware to change the application's language based on the user's language:
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $languageText = $user->language_text;
            $language = $this->languageMapping[$languageText] ?? 'en';

            if (in_array($language, ['en', 'fr', 'de', 'it'])) {
                App::setLocale($language);
                session(['locale' => $language]);
            } else {
                App::setLocale('en'); // Default language
                session(['locale' => 'en']);
            }
        } else {
            App::setLocale(session('locale', 'en')); // Default language
        }

        return $next($request);
    }


Im' working with laravel 11, no kernel.php...
this is my app.php:


return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
   ->withRouting(
       web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
       commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
       health: '/up',
   )
   ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
       $middleware->alias([
           'role' => CheckRole::class
       ]);

       $middleware->append(SetUserLanguage::class);
   })

   ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
       //
   })->create();


The middleware works, but Auth::check() gives me always false and also Auth::user() is always null. The session works, I tried with static datas and the language changed.
I can I manage with Auth()?

You could have registered the SetUserLanguage before the Auth middleware, can you share your app/Http/Kernel.php file?

you logged in from API or web?

I'm logged from web
